# Logstash File Input Not Writing to Elasticsearch Installation on AWS EC2

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am using Logstash version 7.8.0 and Elasticsearch version 7.7.1, both installed on an AWS EC2 instance.

I have the following logstash config in my `conf.d` directory:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/ec2-user/logs/app.log"
    type => "syslog"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

But the problem if that it is not writing logs to Elasticsearch `logstash` index.

Logs show that it is successfully connecting to Elasticsearch.

Same configuration/setup works fine on my local machine (Ubuntu) but does not work on AWS Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Can you start Logtash with the following switch on the command line `--log.level debug` and provide the log output?

Comment: Sure, I'm getting an error when pasting the logs. It says the body is limited to 30000 characters but I entered 64000. Is there another way to send it?

Comment: [gist it](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: Thanks, please see this: https://gist.github.com/codocean/edb786933c02135db70ba1d1949df727

Comment: it doesn't look like you're connecting to AWS ES but localhost

Comment: yes I updated the title, its ES and Logstash both installed on the same EC2 instance.

Comment: Can you share your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file?

Comment: sure: https://gist.github.com/codocean/e8660076b2ae867e427f3f89b2b9555a

Comment: Thanks and also the logs from your ES server when it starts up.

Comment: Also can you define what you mean by "does not work"? because the logs say that Logstash can successfully connect to ES, even on AWS

Comment: sure, I just restarted it to get the log (not sure if I had the same error when I started it last time): https://gist.github.com/codocean/593e3a5fde4294bdaf2bf840255e2c33

Comment: Can you try to connect to `10.0.22.135:9200` instead of `localhost:9200`?

Comment: thanks, i just did but I still don't see the data in ES. Here is logstash log: https://gist.github.com/codocean/51cbea151f76cc003f75cb67622b6e64

Comment: It should be writing in the `logstash-xyz` index

Comment: the only index with logstash in prefix is this 'logstash-2020.06.19-000001' and it has 0 hits.

Comment: Can you check http://localhost:9600/_node/stats/?pretty to see if events are actually flowing through Logstash at all ?

Comment: there are 0 events: https://gist.github.com/codocean/2efbcc65eb61a4d4e6d44cfbe3fd6aae

Comment: And are you sure that your input file `/home/ec2-user/logs/app.log` actually exists and you have the rights to read it?

Comment: yes its actually the name of the company (not app.log) and I verified with an `ls` directly to the path in the conf file to verify that its there and constantly updated.

Comment: Can you provide the full log from Logstash, because the last link didn't contain everything I think

Comment: when i start with this command `sudo systemctl start logstash.service` it only provides that log (maybe because of log4j.properties settings), but when I start with this `bin/logstash --log.level debug --path.settings /etc/logstash` I get that longer log (I have to `su` to logstash to make it work). Its here: https://gist.github.com/codocean/d67ddb62b29360bfa4a8628bfd0eefa9

Comment: also I verified that read is open to the world for the log file

Comment: thanks again, it was in fact the permissions issue. the directory must be both readable and executable for 'logstash' user to be able to read (it was just readable). but there were no error/warnings/traces even when i turned on trace logs.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 3.5 days of my life on this because there are no logs indicating the problem even when you set the logging to Trace, I found the problem is that the directory (including all the parent directories of that directory) containing the input log file must have both "read" and "execute" permission open to "world" for "logstash" program to read and index these files in Elasticsearch.

To get `trace` logs, do the following:

In '/etc/logstash/logstash.yml', add:
`log.level: trace`

In '/etc/logstash/conf.d/your-config-file.conf', add:

```
output {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```